# How can I append pictures which is not exist on folder?

Tags: file, batch-file, move

I want to write .bat file,
I have two folders which names are  A and B.
I have pictures on A , and I want to transfer them from A to B in every 10 minutes,
But I want to transfer the last 20 pictures. Pictures names are 1.jpg 2.jpg ,,,,90.jpg
How can I do that? Is it possible?

thanks

Comment: so "the last 20" are `71.jpg` to `90.jpg`?

Comment: yes , I want that , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"

SET /a numbertomove=20

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d /o-d "%sourcedir%\*.jpg"^|findstr /n "."'
  ) DO (
 IF %%a leq %numbertomove% ECHO MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%b" "%destdir%\"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

---

Edited to remove self-scheduling.

Comment: why the batch file is open after I run it? I want to close cmd screen when finish command

Comment: Because you said you wanted to do this every 10 minutes, so the process must keep running. If you want to schedule it yourself using `Task Scheduler`, then remove the `choice...` and `goto loop` lines.

Comment: I want to schedule it myself so please update your greate answer , Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

to move the files you can use:

```
for /l %%i in (71,1,90) do move a\%%i.jpg b\%%i.jpg
```

For scheduling a task to run every 10 minutes see `schtasks /create /?`.
There are a lot of options, collect them to your needs.

It's a bit confusing to get the right syntax if you do it the first time, so you may have to ask a new question if you know, which options you want to use.

(NOTE: to use the `for`construct on commandline (not in batch) use single`%` instead of `%%`)

Comment: how can I do it dynamically , I mean it is not static for 71-90

Comment: Put more information into your question about what you really need to do.  If it is the 20 most recently created files, then say so.